How can I use a self-defined RDF compression format, such as Protobuf, in my project?
Working with RDF Streams in Apache Jena: "If you want to use an alternative compression format you can do so by adding suitable dependencies into your project and passing an appropriate InputStream/OutputStream implementation to Jena code e.g."
InputStream input =  new ZstdCompressorInputStream(....);
Graph graph = RDFParser.source(input).lang(Lang.NQ).toGraph();

What does it means?
I have just learned the Protobuf format about RDF and StreamRDF, but it's hard for me to use a self-defined format in my project to compress RDF stream. I want to konw how to follow above suggestion and I need a practical advice.

I'm not sure what exactly you are asking for, but there are already implementations for binary encoding in Jena, either based on Thrift or Protobuf: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/rdf-binary.html
